# Why doesn't this code for a navigation drawer work?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

Following is some code to create a navigation drawer. The problem is that the drawer doesn't appear properly. The drawer is visible from the start of the activity but only partially, and it doesn't slide in and out from the side. It's just stationary in one place. What's wrong here?

NOTE: I've removed the Action Bar by writing `NoActionBar` in `styles.xml`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.navigationexample3.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

   <
   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/nv"
   >


   <ListView
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>

   </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nirvan.navigationexample3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView ls=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] values=
    {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight"};


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    R.layout.item,values);
    ls.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
 }
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

Comment: You're missing the appropriate `layout_gravity` attribute on your drawer `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your layout file like this:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

         <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                    android:id="@+id/my"/>
                <ListView

                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/list_view_inside_nav"></ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: But why should the `LinearLayout` enclose the `Navigation View`? My understanding is that the first `LinearLayout`is for when the drawer is hidden. And the  `Navigation View` conatins the content of the drawer. So why should `LinearLayout` enclose the View?

Comment: if you want to use a listview to show the option inside the drawer menu, you can use the layout above (edited)

Comment: So where does the xml code for the remaining app go? I'm talking about the  part that shows when the drawer is hidden.

Comment: Also please explain the <include > statement. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luiz Fernando's reply, don't forget to put

```
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

At the end of your XML file.